# SSIS with Microsoft Big Data platform

Tags: ssis, bigdata, azure-hdinsight

Can we use SSIS with Microsoft Big Data Platform and What are the areas SSIS would still be useful with Big Data

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the points mentioned by @GregGalloway you should have a look at the [SSIS Azure Feature Pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt146770.aspx), which is currently still in preview. It contains some tasks for working with HDInsight, for example for Hive and Pig. If you need a deeper integration, especially with other services in Azure such as DocumentDB, Data Factory should be on the top of your list.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. If you don't have SSIS now then you might look at Azure Data Factory first. But if you do use SSIS currently you can use it with HDInsight.

If you install the Hive ODBC driver (or Spark ODBC or both) you can connect in SSIS with a connection string like and use an ODBC source or an Execute SQL task.

uid=MyUser;pwd=MyPassword;Driver={Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver};host=mycluster.azurehdinsight.net;port=443;schema=default;rowsfetchedperblock=10000;hiveservertype=2;authmech=6;defaultstringcolumnlength=4000;

See a slightly different ODBC walk through here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver/

However I prefer putting my Hive code in .hql files in blob storage then having SSIS use Azure PowerShell to launch them. That's somewhat the equivalent of deploying a "stored proc".

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Microsoft SSIS to interact with Big data with the help of Open Database Connectivity.
Have a look at this tutorial where SSIS has been used to push data into HIVE table of Cloudera.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPLfcL2zDX8